# Running MP3 files before downloading in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Currently I have an app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.os.bkdownloader which downloads mp3, pdfs etc over internet..
Now I would like to enhance it by providing "play" option for mp3. So after clicking the "play" they should be able to listen first. Currently it is directly downloading it.

How can I achieve this?

I went through examples on MediaPlayer implementation but couldn't get any promising way.

Any help will appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: First of all, you know that to "play" it on the android, you're actualy downloading it and playing it before the download finishes, right ?

Comment: What you want to do is called streaming. There are countless examples/tutorials on the web. Try a search for it.